# How do I insert my new environment variable into a directive?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am on a server where my only available ability to configure Apache is via .htaccess files. So, no adding Apache modules, no httpd.conf access, etc. Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu Linux.

I need to create a new environment variable based on an existing environment variable.

```
SetEnv my_new_var /debug/path/to/password/.passwd
SetEnvIf PREESTABLISHED_VAR "a" my_new_var=/first/path/to/password/.passwd
SetEnvIf PREESTABLISHED_VAR "b" my_new_var=/second/path/to/password/.passwd
AuthType basic
AuthName "User name"
AuthUserFile ???????
Require valid-user
```

What do I put for the value of AuthUserFile to substitute the value of my_new_var for the question marks?

```
AuthUserFile my_new_var
```

produces the log error

```
No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/my_new_var

AuthUserFile $my_new_var
```

produces the log error

```
No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/$my_new_var

AuthUserFile ${my_new_var}
```

produces the log error

```
No such file or directory: Could not open password file: /etc/apache2/${my_new_var}
```

(As side notes which should not likely affect the solution, the authentication is being served using https, not http; the password file is outside the document system; and the passwords within are hashed.)